# WPF set window height sized to content and width adjustable manually

Tags: wpf, resize, sizetocontent

In WPF I have a window for which I want the height to be sized to content (and adjusted dynamically as I have an **Expander** in it) and prevent the user from being able to change it but let him/her being able to change the width of the window.

How can I achieve this?

**SizeToContent** does half the trick as it doesn’t restrict manual changing the height.
**ResizeMode** cannot prevent changing just the height or the width.
And in the **SizeChanged** event I cannot distinguish if the change is initiated automatically or by the user to prevent changing the height.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `FrameworkElement.MinHeight` and `FrameworkElement.MaxHeight` properties to freeze the current height of the `Window`

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Lock the initial height from the Loaded event handler
    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => LockWindowHeight();
  
  private void LockWindowHeight()
    => this.MinHeight = this.MaxHeight = this.ActualHeight;

  private void SetWindowHeight(double newHeight)
  {    
    this.MinHeight = double.IsNormal(newHeight) ? newHeight : 0;
    this.MaxHeight = double.IsNormal(newHeight) ? newHeight : double.PositiveInfinity;
    this.Height = newHeight;
  }

  // For the sake of completeness
  private void UnlockWindowHeight(double newHeight)
  {    
    this.MinHeight = 0;
    this.MaxHeight = double.PositiveInfinity;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @BionicCode.

This does not solve the problem with the change of the window height when the Expander is expanded.
It did form the basis for the end solution, though so I accepted it as an answer.

Comment: You want to resize the window based on the Expander state? When it is expanded then increase the window height and when it is collapsed then reduce the window height? That is an odd user experience, don't you agree? In this case I suggest to enable the ScrollViewer and scroll the Expander into view to make it fully visible.

Comment: Consider this answer as the foundation. All you have to do is to handle the `Expander.Expanded` event and call the above `SetWindowHeight` where the new height is `Window.ActualHeight + Expander.ActualHeight`. You can backup the original window height before setting the new height. Additionally, you would also handle the `Expander.Collapsed` event and again call `SetWindowHeight` where the new height is `backupHeight + Expander.ActualHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

For the full solution several event handlers and a simple method need to be added:

```
...
expander.Expanded += Expander_StateChanged;
expander.Collapsed += Expander_StateChanged;
this.SizeChanged += Window_SizeChanged;
...

private void Expander_StateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => AdjustWindowHeight();

private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
  => LockWindowHeight();

void AdjustWindowHeight()
{
    UnlockWindowHeight();
    this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Height;
}
```